# call base class function in derived class constructor

Tags: c++, inheritance

I know it's OK to call base class function in a derived class constructor, because base class is constructed before derived class.But I'm not sure if this is a good practice.Example code is:

```cpp
class Base {
 public:
  int Get() const { return i_; }
  void Set(const int i) { i_ = i; }

 private:
  int i_{0};
};

class Derived : public Base {
  // initialize `derived_i_` with a call to base class function, Is this a good
  // practice in production code?
  Derived() : derived_i_{Get()} {
    // do some other things
  }

 private:
  int derived_i_{0};
};
```

Comment: How should `Base::Get()` ever return something different but `0` when called from the member initialization list of `Derived()`?

Comment: @Swordfish This is just a example, `i_` may changes.

Comment: *`i_` may change* – How?

Comment: @Swordfish OK, I made a mistake, `i_` will never change.

Comment: Maybe you find a better example then.

Comment: @Swordfish Let `i_` alwalys be `0`, do you thik this is a good practice, does it has some risk in my code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192992/discussion-between-swordfish-and-maidamai).

Answer (score 1):

To be more pedantic, you could write your constructor as the following:

```
Derived() : Base(), derived_i_{Get()} {
  // do some other things
}
```

The compiler should fully construct the base class before doing any initialization of the derived class.